# how to access the fragment that not added to viewpageradapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity Contains a viewpager and 6 fragment.4 fragmens added to adapter,but 2  other fragments dont added.
my problem that cannot access to this 2 fragments from activity?
is someone help me?

NoT:I replace first fragment of that 4 fragments with other 2 fragment when an item in first fragment clicked.

Comment: you should provide some code, do you keep a reference to those 2 fragments? are they created right away during the replacement stage?